# Please what does "dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null &" do?

Tags: linux, dd

What does this command do?

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null &
```

I really don't understand what that command counts, because when I run it, it returns 4 figured numbers e.g 6204.

Comment: I cannot stress this enough. ***If you don't know what a command does, then do not run it!***. Especially if that command is `dd`, a very powerful and unsophisticated tool that can delete all of your data (don't worry, this one should be safe).

Comment: in addition to the answer below, another way to say what will happen is that command will cause one process of `dd`  to run indefinitely taking up 1 cpu core, which will show 100% under top for CPU%.  *a poor man's stress test on a single cpu core using no ram*.  Won't necessarily hurt anything other than generate a small forever busy process.  It, technically, will slow down your system.

Comment: If the `of=` referred to a file, the command would fill the file system before it crashed. If the file already existed, it would be lost immediately. On the other hand, if the `of=` referred to a block device (like a disk partition), the entire device or partition would be wiped completely. `dd` is usually referred to as `disc destroyer`, although Divine Dynamite also works. You were lucky this time. How are your backups ?

Comment: @terdon, and Paul_Pedant, note however that what `dd` does isn't in principle much different from what `cat` does. Both copy stuff from a file or stdin to stdout. (`dd` can just do it with a set block size, and can set the output file itself, without needing shell redirections.) Of course, one should be careful with commands like `dd if=image.bin of=/dev/sdd1`, but `cat image.bin > /dev/sdd1` would be equally dangerous. It's the filename that starts with `/dev/` that one should be careful with...

Comment: @ilkkachu sure, and my advice to not run commands if you don't know what they are applies to cat and everything else. It's just even more important with something like dd that can be missused so easily.

Answer (score 8):

It reads bytes from `/dev/zero` and puts them into `/dev/null`.

`/dev/zero` only outputs 0's when you read from it. `/dev/null` is a bitbucket which just discards whatever you write into it.

If you don't specify a count it will just read until the end of the file. Which in the case `/dev/zero` will go on forever.

You can specify a count by:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null count=10
```

This will default to 10 counts of 512 bytes from `/dev/zero`.

You can also specify a block size:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null bs=1024 count=10
```

---

The numbers that you see is the process id. This is shown because you send the command to background with `&`.

As mentioned above, the command will not end until you quit the terminal, restart your computer or kill the process using `kill`, `pkill` or  by running `fg` and then pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Comment: Additionally, `kill %[job number]` will kill background jobs by their number, which can be found by running the command `jobs`